# Spark 1.2.1 standalone cluster mode spark-submit is not working

Tags: apache-spark

I have 3 node spark cluster

node1 , node2 and node 3

I running below command on node 1 for deploying driver

/usr/local/spark-1.2.1-bin-hadoop2.4/bin/`spark-submit` --class com.fst.firststep.aggregator.FirstStepMessageProcessor --master spark://ec2-xx-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077 --deploy-mode cluster --supervise file:///home/xyz/sparkstreaming-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /home/xyz/config.properties

driver gets launched on node 2 in cluster. but getting exception on node 2 that it is trying to bind to node 1 ip.

```
2015-02-26 08:47:32 DEBUG AkkaUtils:63 - In createActorSystem, requireCookie is: off 
2015-02-26 08:47:32 INFO  Slf4jLogger:80 - Slf4jLogger started 
2015-02-26 08:47:33 ERROR NettyTransport:65 - failed to bind to ec2-xx.xx.xx.xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/xx.xx.xx.xx:0, shutting down Netty transport 
2015-02-26 08:47:33 WARN  Utils:71 - Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1. 
2015-02-26 08:47:33 DEBUG AkkaUtils:63 - In createActorSystem, requireCookie is: off 
2015-02-26 08:47:33 ERROR Remoting:65 - Remoting error: [Startup failed] [ 
akka.remote.RemoteTransportException: Startup failed 
        at akka.remote.Remoting.akka$remote$Remoting$$notifyError(Remoting.scala:136) 
        at akka.remote.Remoting.start(Remoting.scala:201) 
        at akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider.init(RemoteActorRefProvider.scala:184) 
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.liftedTree2$1(ActorSystem.scala:618) 
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start$lzycompute(ActorSystem.scala:615) 
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl._start(ActorSystem.scala:615) 
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.start(ActorSystem.scala:632) 
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:141) 
        at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:118) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:121) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:54) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1765) 
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:141) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1756) 
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:56) 
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:33) 
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala) 
Caused by: org.jboss.netty.channel.ChannelException: Failed to bind to: ec2-xx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/xx.xx.xx.xx:0 
        at org.jboss.netty.bootstrap.ServerBootstrap.bind(ServerBootstrap.java:272) 
        at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:393) 
        at akka.remote.transport.netty.NettyTransport$$anonfun$listen$1.apply(NettyTransport.scala:389) 
        at scala.util.Success$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Try.scala:206) 
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161) 
        at scala.util.Success.map(Try.scala:206)
```

kindly suggest

Thanks

Comment: Are your spark workers properly connected to master?Please verify once.

Comment: workers are properly connected as it works if i use client deployment mode

Answer (score 7):

after spending lot more time.i got the answer.i did below changes

1. remove entry of SPARK_LOCAL_IP and SPARK_MASTER_IP
2. add host name and private ip address of each other nodes in etc/hosts.
3. use --deploy-mode cluster --supervise

thats all and it works perfectly with fully HA components(Master,Slaves and Driver)

Thanks

Comment: This deserves hella thumbs up!!! Thanks to you I can stop doing devops and start doing developing. This should be documented.

Comment: Where are these entries:  remove entry of SPARK_LOCAL_IP and SPARK_MASTER_IP

Comment: @JustinThomas the SPARK_LOCAL_IP and SPARK_MASTER_IP settings reside in ./conf/spark-env.sh

Answer (score 2):

Cluster mode is not supported in EC2 1.2 instances where it creates a standalone cluster. Hence you can try removing

```
--deploy-mode cluster --supervise
```

Comment: if i remove cluster mode then it starts in client mode and it works fine there.issue is only in cluster mode. is there any specific reason cluster mode is not supported in ec2. as per the spark doc it says it is supported in 1.2.1 release please share if you have more info on that

Comment: Common deployment strategy for EC2 is client mode as they are emphasising even though it is not specifically mentioned. Do you have any specific reason to use cluster mode

Comment: the only reason is we need Driver HA. as in client mode if my Driver gets down the entire application will be down. but in cluster mode  with --supervise  flag it reruns it.