# spark submit "Service 'Driver' could not bind on port" error

Tags: apache-spark, word-count

I used the following command to run the spark java example of wordcount:-

```
time spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster --master spark://192.168.0.7:6066 --class org.apache.spark.examples.JavaWordCount /home/pi/Desktop/example/new/target/javaword.jar /books_50.txt
```

When I run it, the following is the output:-

```
Running Spark using the REST application submission protocol.
16/07/18 03:55:41 INFO rest.RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request to launch an application in spark://192.168.0.7:6066.
16/07/18 03:55:44 INFO rest.RestSubmissionClient: Submission successfully created as driver-20160718035543-0000. Polling submission state...
16/07/18 03:55:44 INFO rest.RestSubmissionClient: Submitting a request for the status of submission driver-20160718035543-0000 in spark://192.168.0.7:6066.
16/07/18 03:55:44 INFO rest.RestSubmissionClient: State of driver driver-20160718035543-0000 is now RUNNING.
16/07/18 03:55:44 INFO rest.RestSubmissionClient: Driver is running on worker worker-20160718041005-192.168.0.12-42405 at 192.168.0.12:42405.
16/07/18 03:55:44 INFO rest.RestSubmissionClient: Server responded with CreateSubmissionResponse:
{
  "action" : "CreateSubmissionResponse",
  "message" : "Driver successfully submitted as driver-20160718035543-0000",
  "serverSparkVersion" : "1.6.2",
  "submissionId" : "driver-20160718035543-0000",
  "success" : true
}
```

I checked the particular worker (192.168.0.12) for its log and it says:-

```
Launch Command: "/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-8-oracle-arm32-vfp-hflt/jre/bin/java" "-cp" "/opt/spark/conf/:/opt/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.2-hadoop2.6.0.jar:/opt/spark/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar:/opt/spark/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar:/opt/spark/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" "-Xms1024M" "-Xmx1024M" "-Dspark.driver.supervise=false" "-Dspark.app.name=org.apache.spark.examples.JavaWordCount" "-Dspark.submit.deployMode=cluster" "-Dspark.jars=file:/home/pi/Desktop/example/new/target/javaword.jar" "-Dspark.master=spark://192.168.0.7:7077" "-Dspark.executor.memory=10M" "org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper" "spark://Worker@192.168.0.12:42405" "/opt/spark/work/driver-20160718035543-0000/javaword.jar" "org.apache.spark.examples.JavaWordCount" "/books_50.txt"
========================================

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.lib.MutableMetricsFactory).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/07/18 04:10:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: pi
16/07/18 04:10:58 INFO SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: pi
16/07/18 04:10:58 INFO SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users with view permissions: Set(pi); users with modify permissions: Set(pi)
16/07/18 04:11:00 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/07/18 04:11:00 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/07/18 04:11:00 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/07/18 04:11:00 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/07/18 04:11:00 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/07/18 04:11:00 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/07/18 04:11:00 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/07/18 04:11:00 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/07/18 04:11:00 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/07/18 04:11:00 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/07/18 04:11:00 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/07/18 04:11:00 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/07/18 04:11:00 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/07/18 04:11:00 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/07/18 04:11:00 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
16/07/18 04:11:00 WARN Utils: Service 'Driver' could not bind on port 0. Attempting port 1.
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: Service 'Driver' failed after 16 retries! Consider explicitly setting the appropriate port for the service 'Driver' (for example spark.ui.port for SparkUI) to an available port or increasing spark.port.maxRetries.
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketChannel.doBind(NioServerSocketChannel.java:125)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.bind(AbstractChannel.java:485)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1089)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeBind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:430)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.bind(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:415)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.bind(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:903)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.bind(AbstractChannel.java:198)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap$2.run(AbstractBootstrap.java:348)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My spark-env.sh file (for master) contains:-

```
export SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT="8080"
export SPARK_MASTER_IP="192.168.0.7"
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY="10M"
```

My spark-env.sh file (for worker) contains:-

```
export SPARK_WORKER_WEBUI_PORT="8080"
export SPARK_MASTER_IP="192.168.0.7"
export SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY="10M"
```

Please help...!!

Comment: where you ever able to resolve this issue? i'm having exactly the same problem with spark v2.0.0.

Comment: Hi, I was not able to find any leads for this particular issue. Therefore, I started streaming the python example for wordcount. Please let me know if you find out a workaround.

Answer (score 22):

I had the same issue when trying to run the shell, and was able to get this working by setting the SPARK_LOCAL_IP environment variable. You can assign this from the command line when running the shell:

`SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1 ./bin/spark-shell`

For a more permanent solution, create a spark-env.sh file in the conf directory of your Spark root. Add the following line:

`SPARK_LOCAL_IP=127.0.0.1`

Give execute permissions to the script using `chmod +x ./conf/spark-env.sh`, and this will set this environment variable by default.

Comment: Doing an `export` for `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` before starting the script worked for me - to quickly test if this would work or not.

Answer (score 12):

I am using Maven/SBT to manage dependencies and the Spark core is contained in a jar file.

You can override the SPARK_LOCAL_IP at runtime by setting the "spark.driver.bindAddress" (here in Scala):

```
val config = new SparkConf()
config.setMaster("local[*]")
config.setAppName("Test App")
config.set("spark.driver.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1")
val sc = new SparkContext(config)
```

Answer (score 4):

I also had this issue.

The reason (for me) was that the IP of my local system was not reachable from my local system.
I know that statement makes no sense, but please read the following.

My system name (uname -s) shows that my system is named "sparkmaster".
In my /etc/hosts file, I have assigned a fixed IP address for the sparkmaster system as "192.168.1.70". There were additional fixed IP addresses for sparknode01 and sparknode02 at ...1.71 & ...1.72 respectively.

Due to some other problems I had, I needed to change all of my network adapters to DHCP. This meant that they were getting addresses like 192.168.90.123.
The DHCP addresses were not in the same network as the ...1.70 range and there was no route configured.

When spark starts, is seems to want to try to connect to the host named in uname (i.e. sparkmaster in my case). This was the IP 192.168.1.70 - but there was no way to connect to that because that address was in an unreachable network.

My solution was to change one of my Ethernet adapters back to a fixed static address (i.e. 192.168.1.70) and voila - problem solved.

So the issues seems to be that when spark starts in "local mode" it attempts to connect to a system named after your system's name (rather than local host).
I guess this makes sense if you are wanting to setup a cluster (Like I did) but it can result in the above confusing message.
Possibly putting your system's host name on the 127.0.0.1 entry in /etc/hosts may also solve this problem, but I did not try it.

Comment: Same issue - hostname was "45131" which spark treats as an IP.

Comment: LOL, a numeric only host name may cause all sorts of challenges.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enter the hostname in your `/etc/hosts` file.
Something like:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost "hostname"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Manav. I tried adding/deleting/editing the line to the hosts file but it doesn't change anything whatsoever.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is related to your network settings and not your spark setup. I got the same error  and was able to solve it by adding an entry in the hosts file. Just to be sure, you need to replace the "hostname" in the last cmd with your hostname (type $hostname cmd in your shell), also no quotes

Comment: This is the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly a duplicate of [Spark 1.2.1 standalone cluster mode spark-submit is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778774/spark-1-2-1-standalone-cluster-mode-spark-submit-is-not-working)

I have tried the same steps, but able to run the job. Kindly post the full spark-env.sh and spark-defaults if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and it is because of changing real IP with my IP in /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is related to IP address alone. Error messages in the log file are not informative.
check with following 3 steps:

1. check your IP address - can be checked with ifconfig or ip commands. If your service is not a Public service. IP addresses with 192.168 should be good enough. 127.0.0.1 cannot be used if you are planning a cluster.
2. check your environment variable SPARK_MASTER_HOST - check there are no typos in the name of the variable or actual IP address.

   env | grep SPARK_
3. check the port you are planning to use for sparkMaster is free with command netstat. Do not use a port below 1024. For example:

   netstat -a | 9123

After your sparkmaster starts running if you are not able see webui from a different machine, then open the webui port with command iptables.

Answer (score 0):

Use as below in dataframes

val spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("BinarizerExample").master("local[*]").config("spark.driver.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1").getOrCreate()

Answer (score 0):

**First Option :-**

Following steps might help:

```
Get your hostname by using "hostname" command.

 xxxxxx.ssssss  (e) base  ~  hostname
 xxxxxx.ssssss.net
```

Make an entry in the **/etc/hosts** file for your hostname if not present as follows:

```
127.0.0.1      xxxxxx.ssssss.net
```

**Second Option:-**

you can set **spark.driver.bindAddress** value in your spark.conf file

```
spark.driver.bindAddress=127.0.0.1
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score -2):

I solved this problem by modifying the slave file.its spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/conf/slave
please check your configure。